# How do I save a text file into an array?

Tags: c

This is how I print out the text file

```
FILE *file;
char array[200];

file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

fread(array,1, 200, file);
printf("\n%s", array);
fclose(file);
```

Instead I want to save the text file rows to an array so i can print out the text file with the array.

I can only use those fopen,fprintf,fwrite,fscanf,fread,fseek,fclose. Not fget.

How do i save the text file lines to an array?

Comment: Don't forget to check that the calls worked.  Don't forget to save the return value from `fread()`; you need it to know how many bytes to write.  You need to use a more complex `printf()` format because the string you read won't be null-terminated. If you got an `int nbytes = fread(…);` then you need `printf("%*.*s\n", n, n, array)` to write the data.  Note that newlines go at the end of the output line, not the beginning.  How big is the text file?  Less than 200 characters or bigger?  Do you need the whole file in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `fscanf` you can read data in file and store it in a 2-d `char` array . Something like this -

```
char array[20][200];              // array to hold data in file
int i=0;
file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if(file==NULL){                   // error in opening file
        //handle it
 }
while(fscanf(file,"%199[^\n]%*c",array[i])==1){
      // handle your data 
      i++;             // increment index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a `mmap` and then work with the memory which reflects the content of your file. No explicit "loading" is required in that case. Man mmap.